# SQL Server : how to get rid of same/opposite values (+ and - sign) from select result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to ask how I can get rid of the same values from select result (screenshot below) but different symbol in this case + and - sign. I am using SQL Server.

My solution: I have created a `cte` (or another select) with unique identifier using `concat` (No, Value, value2) which will return only records with same rows which differs in symbol (+ and -), then  final select without values from cte.

```
select* 
from myTable 
except values from mycte
```

[image: Select result]

My question is if there is any faster, better, clever solution for similar situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `not exists` does what you want.  Assuming that `symbol` only takes on the values `'+'` and `'-'`:

```
select t.*
from myTable t
where not exists (select 1
                  from myTable t2
                  where t2.no = t.no and t2.date = t.date and
                        t2.value = t.value and
                        t2.value2 = t.value2 and
                        t2.provision = t.provision and
                        t2.symbol <> t.symbol
                 );
```

If `symbol` can take on other values, then add the condition `t2.symbol in ('+', '-') and t.symbol in ('+', '-')`.

You could also approach this using window functions.  Assuming symbol is either `+` or `-` and there are at most two rows that get duplicated:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(symbol) over (partition by no, date, value, value2, provision) as min_symbol,
             min(symbol) over (partition by no, date, value, value2, provision) as max_symbol
      from mytable t
     ) t
where min_symbol <> max_symbol;
```